# Google Maps Multiple Circles

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Guys i have been doing this project related to google places and maps apis.
What i want to do is search for the nearest restaurants. But I can't place multiple circles on the map. One marker is visible there on the map for the user's current location. Here is the code.

```
func setUpMarkersForLibraries(locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]){
print("Setting up Markers")
var i = 0
for l in locations{
    let circleCenter = l
    let circ = GMSCircle(position: circleCenter, radius: 30)

    circ.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.89, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
    circ.strokeColor = .black
    circ.strokeWidth = 5
    circ.title = "\(i)"
    circ.map = mapView

}
}
```

I pass the coordinates for all the locations i get using Google Places API web service. So there are total 20 locations so there should be 20 markers. But there is none. Please let me know what i am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Do you add your mapview to your view?
self.view = mapView

Comment: Yes i do that in my viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @AnthonyTaylor What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using the simulator or phone?

Comment: I am using Simulator

Answer (score 0):

This Function looks fine.

It could be that the marker, once drawn to the map is not updated. Unlike the user's location which is. The Circles are most likely being added.

Call your method before/during the marker is added to the map... For MapKit the function I would use to create a custom Annotation/Marker is:

mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?

This is better than just adding a circle to the coordinates, as it becomes a property of the marker, rather than a map overlay.

A quick look at the documentation also suggests that GMSMarker property iconView can also be used to add a custom view.

Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: I  am not using MapKit. And also what do you mean by "call your method begore/during the marker is added to the map.

Comment: Call your  setUpMarkersForLibraries() before setting the maker to the map:  marker.map = mapView, I am assuming you are iterating an array.

Comment: If you are iterating an array I suppose you can use something similar to this? 

`var Libraries: [GMSMarker] = []

for markers in Libraries {

//create a circle using uiview
let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0))
circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50
circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
circle.alpha = 0.8
circle.clipsToBounds = true

//add the circle to the iconView
markers.iconView = circle

//add library to map
marker.map = Mapview
} `